# How would an atmosphere of 30% oxygen affect a planet's inhabitants?

Tags: science-based

Please answer quickly, this is for a school project due tomorrow.

**The Planet**

The atmosphere is 30% oxygen which, from my research, would make dragonflies grow to have a wingspan of 2 feet and would make fires start more easily. I've decided that the dragonflies could be pets but I'm not sure how to deal with the fires. I thought about making it a sort of "swamp planet". It's covered in water to prevent fires from starting. The question is,

**How will these changes affect the inhabitants?**

I thought that they might have webbing between their fingers but I'm still not sure. Any suggestions?

Edit: Several good points have been made. The question now is "Is a planet with a nitrogen-oxygen atmosphere feasible, if the percentage of oxygen is 30%? Would this gas mix be prone to explosions, or fires which would ravage the world?" The fires were my first concern which is why I chose to make it a swamp planet but I'm not sure how realistic this is.

This is not intended to be the community doing my homework for me- I'm asking for help because I actually want to work with this world after the project is over and I want it to be a good one.

Comment: Not only is WB SE _not_ a homework-help website, but your question is not tailored to site standards. Essentially, you're giving us 2 parameters regarding your world, and asking us to fill in the many, many blanks. That's not how it's done. You have to flesh out your world a _lot more_ before asking us for more advice, validation, or ideas. So _my suggestion_ is that you think about your question a little bit more, and come back with something which fits site standards, not a request for us to do your homework.

Comment: You need to specify far more details before we can create a coherent answer.

Comment: @Garto Keep in mind AndreiROM words - we're not here to do the OP's homework.

Comment: Sorry, I just really don't know what to do.

Comment: What comprises the other 70% of the atmosphere? You tell us that the planet is covered with water, but to what percentage? What's the climate like? Is it a swamp planet, or an ocean planet? What sort of species inhabit it? Deep dwelling fish type beings? Mammalian life-forms? Flying monsters which also swim to the bottom of the ocean? How would you keep a 30% atmosphere from igniting into insane fire storms every time there's a spark? There's so many details I don't even know where to begin. Perhaps start by asking ***"is a planet with a 30% oxygen rich atmosphere scientifically feasible"***.

Comment: About 300 million years ago Earth had 35% oxygen. See what lived then and start with that. @AndreiROM - no need to ask about feasibility, we've been there.

Comment: I would start by asking a question tagged "Science-based", which asks: **""Is a planet with a nitrogen-oxygen atmosphere feasible, if the percentage of oxygen is 30%? Would this gas mix be prone to explosions, or fires which would ravage the world?"** Once you have an answer to that, in the next couple of hours, you might be able to proceed with asking other questions, and building an idea of what your world might be like.

Comment: @Mołot  - I actually wasn't aware of that little tid-bit of information - goes to show all the interesting things you can learn by participating on this site. I was simply trying to get the OP down the path of building his world. For example, I think your comment (but fleshed out) would constitute a good basis for him to ask a second question along the lines of **"what sort of life forms first inhabited the earth, _bla bla bla_"** (but you know, on scope). A tangential question might be **"How easily would fire storms start in this environment, _bla bla bla_"**

Comment: Google will help you, Tyler.  I googled "oxygen in the atmosphere history" and hit loads of info you can use.  Find out what was different when O2 was 30% as re atmosphere, humidity, temperature, sunlight.  Cite your source(s) for a real teacher pleaser.  Then extrapolate creatively how those differences might affect us today.

Comment: While I agree with the comments from the others that you haven't really asked a question which fits this site and that we're not here to do your homework; I can't help but add: if this *were* a homework helping site, shouldn't you have asked this slightly more ahead of time than just the day before? If you want answers, then don't expect a good one to jump at you at the last second.

Answer (score 8):

While this question certainly isn't well phrased, or really appropriate for this SE, it is pretty simple to give you a starting point that might let you pose a better question.

In the Late Carboniferous period on earth...

**- "The atmosphere is 30% oxygen"**

The Mean atmospheric Oxygen content during the Carboniferous was 32.5% by volume.

**- "covered in water"**

During the late Carboniferous period, the planet looked like this:
[image: Late Carboniferous Globe]
Seems pretty covered in water to me.

**- "a sort of "swamp planet"**

The lush swamps of the Carboniferous period created much of the coal we use today. However, they were only one of the biomes that flourished during this time period. I don't believe earth was covered entirely by swamps at any point throughout history.

**- "dragonflies grow to have a wingspan of 2 feet"**

Yep, the Carboniferous had giant dragonflies, including the genus Meganeura.

Now, here you have a planet that fulfills many of your criteria, and the best thing is, it existed in real life! Now that you have a model to build off of, I am sure you can customize it however you want. Using details from the Carboniferous period of earth, perhaps you can ask a more specific, better worded question.

Edit: Sorry for the Snark

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboniferous

https://www.britannica.com/science/Carboniferous-Period